# Sinatra Multiple Models / Helpers with same name

Tags: model, routes, sinatra, haml, helper

I am currently running a Sinatra application that can have different versions (different clients). You can switch between the two versions as these use different session variables to identify which system you should be logged into.

The file structure for each of the systems is quite similar, so some of the models and helpers have the same name, but are different in the way they are built - they do the same function but in different ways (i.e variable names, row names).

It should work that when logging into a system, you should only have scope of the helpers and models that are included as part of that system. The file structure is like so:

```
- application.rb 
- routes 
- models 
- views 
- clients 
    - system1 
        - desktop.rb 
        - routes 
        - models 
        - views 
    - system2 
        - desktop.rb 
        - routes 
        - models 
    - helpers
        - views
```

The desktop.rb files contain the relevant routes for only that system, and the desktop.rb file for each system is only loaded as part of the session - the session changes when changing system.

The issue that occurs when switching between systems, sinatra remembers the locations of the old models and helpers as they have the same class names - even though as part of the main application.rb file we only load the desktop.rb file that is relevant.

As part of the login process, the $path variable is set and in the same way when switching systems $path is set again to the new path.

```
$path = session[:systempath]
```

Main desktop.rb file

```
if session[:systemid]
    # Get client / system specific path
    require "./#{$path}/desktop.rb" if $path
end
```

The helpers and models are then required from the routes that are required as part of the desktop.rb file and then called from the route.

```
require_relative "../../models/agent/agent.model.rb"
require_relative "../../helpers/agent/agent.helper.rb"

db = DBAgent.new
```

The issue is then fixed when reloading the application - is there a way to prevent the application remembering the previous models/helpers? If so how would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution is to use load instead of require, because load reloads file each time you ask it. 
But much better solution is to require all libraries and make namespaces. Google for module in ruby as namespace